# Beamer Table Alignment

Tags: tables, beamer, horizontal-alignment

I am wondering how to delete the empty space on the right side of the last column. Also, is there any way to align Panel A and B in beamer?

```
%\documentclass[handout,table,slidestop,compress,mathserif, 10pt]{beamer}
    \documentclass[table,slidestop,compress,mathserif, 10pt]{beamer}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
    \usetheme{Frankfurt}
    %\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm, text margin right=7mm}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage{colortab}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage{bbm}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
    \newcommand{\sumframe}[2]{\psframebox*[fillcolor=sumcolor,border=.5pt,bordercolor=black,shadow=true,shadowcolor=gray]{%
    \parbox[c]{#1}{#2}}}%
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    \usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} 


    \newcommand{\indicator}[1]{\mathbbm{1}_{\left[ {#1} \right] }}
    \usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
    \stackMath
    \newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
    \savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
      \scaleto{%
        \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
        {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
      }{\textheight}% 
    }{0.5ex}}%
    \stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
    }
    \newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}


    \definecolor{dgreen}{rgb}{0.,0.6,0.}
    \definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0.,0.,0.6}
    \definecolor{dred}{rgb}{0.6,0.,0.}



    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


    \title[Title]
    {
      {\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont Title} \\ 
    }



    \author[Name]
    {%
      \texorpdfstring{
          \centering
          Name\\
      }
      {Name}
    }


    \date[September 7, 2017]
    {September 7, 2017}




    % The main document

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \maketitle
    \end{frame}





    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \setcounter{subsection}{6}
    \begin{frame}[label=Survivorship_Result2b]{Subsample test}
    \vspace{-.53cm}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize   
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{5}{Y}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: Group A}} \\
        \midrule
       & \textbf{(1)} & \textbf{(2)} & \textbf{(3)}& \textbf{(4)} & \textbf{(5)}  \\\hline 


    \tikzmark{newcolr}{\textbf{A $\cdot$ B} &\ 0.006& 0.006 &0.006&0.006&0.005  \\
    &\ [4.05]&[2.58]&[3.29]&[3.06]&[4.06]}\\
    \textbf{A} &-0.004& -0.003 & -0.003&-0.003 &-0.003   \\
    &[-6.81]&[-3.49] &[-4.10] &[-3.05]&[-3.35]\\

    \textbf{B} &  &&-0.002&-0.002 \\
    &&& [-1.60]& [-1.55] \\\hline


      \end{tabularx} 
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{5}{Y}}
        \toprule 
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Panel B: Group X}} \\
        \midrule
       & \textbf{(1)} & \textbf{(2)} & \textbf{(3)}& \textbf{(4)} & \textbf{(5)}  \\\hline 

    \tikzmark{colorsa}{\textbf{X $\cdot$ Y} &\ 0.003& 0.002 &0.002&0.002&0.002  \\
    &\ [1.44]&[1.28]&[1.40]&[1.32]&[1.24]}\\
    \textbf{X} &-0.001& 0.000 & 0.000&0.000 &-0.001   \\
    &[-1.67]&[0.04] &[0.04] &[0.04]&[-1.08]\\
    \textbf{Y} &  &&-0.001&-0.001 \\
    &&& [-1.06]& [-1.00]\\ 

    \textbf{Controls}& No& Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes  \\
    \textbf{Group FEs}& Yes& Yes & No & No & Yes  \\
    \textbf{Family FEs}& No& No & Yes & Yes & No  \\
    \textbf{Individual FEs}& No& No & No & Yes & No  \\
    \textbf{Family-Individual Clustering}& Yes& Yes & Yes & Yes& Yes \\
    \textbf{Observations}&8,895&7,654&7,654& 7,654&4,538  \\
    \textbf{R-squared} &0.48&0.53&0.40&0.41 &0.54 \\\hline
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[draw=red,thick,single,fill opacity=0.2] ($(colorsa)+(-0.19,0.28)$) rectangle ($(colorsa)+(11.9,-0.55)$);}

    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[draw=blue,thick,single,fill opacity=0.2] ($(newcolr)+(-0.19,0.28)$) rectangle ($(newcolr)+(11.9,-0.55)$);}


    \end{frame}





    \end{document}
```

Comment: How are your `Y` columns defined?

Comment: please, reduce your document to minimal version which stil demonstrate your problem

Comment: I will post the main part of the code below.

Comment: @Job Please read [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @samcarter, thanks for sharing the link. I will follow the suggestions more carefully. I was a little bit lost at first, but the link and the guidance by Zarko has helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would redesign your table as follows:

- reordered code in editor such that, already in it, the code mimics the  table structure. With this it is simpler to discover all missing parts of code
- merge both tables in one
- remove superfluous rules
- use only rules defined in package `booktabs`
- make your *mwe* works

  1. remove `\tikzmark` stuff (seems to be wrongly used)
  2. instead frame around rows use `\rowcolor`
  3. remove superfluous packages in preamble (like `colorab`, `xcolor`; both are loaded by `beamer` using option `table` ...)
- replace unknown column type `Y` with `S` defined in package `siunitx`
- in *mwe* consider only relevant packages and frame

this effort resulted with:

[image]

```
\documentclass[table,slidestop,compress,mathserif, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm, text margin right=7mm}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{\textbf{#1}}}
\setlength\aboverulesep{1pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{1pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Subsample test}
\label{tab:SR-2b}
    \scriptsize%footnotesize
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
            >{\bfseries}l
            *{6}{S[detect-mode,
                   %input-symbols =  ()[] ,
                   table-space-text-pre ={(},
                   table-space-text-post={)},
                  table-align-text-pre =false,
                  table-align-text-post=false,
                   table-format=-1.3]}
                    }
        \toprule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: Group A}}                       \\
        \midrule
    & \mcx{(1)} & \mcx{(2)} & \mcx{(3)} & \mcx{(4)} & \mcx{(5)}     \\
        \midrule
\rowcolor{blue!20}
A $\cdot$ B
    &  0.006    &  0.006    &  0.006    &  0.006    &  0.005        \\
\rowcolor{blue!20}
    & [4.05]    & [2.58]    & [3.29]    & [3.06]    & [4.06]        \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
A   &  -0.004   &  -0.003   &  -0.003   &  -0.003   &  -0.003       \\
    & [-6.81]   & [-3.49]   & [-4.10]   & [-3.05]   & [-3.35]       \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
B   &           &           &  -0.002   &  -0.002   &               \\
    &           &           & [-1.60]   & [-1.55]   &               \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Panel B: Group X}}                       \\
    \midrule
\rowcolor{red!30}
X $\cdot$ Y
    &  0.003    &  0.002    &  0.002    &  0.002    &  0.002        \\
\rowcolor{red!30}
    & [1.44]    & [1.28]    & [1.40]    & [1.32]    & [1.24]        \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
X   &  -0.001   &  0.000    &  0.000    &  0.000    &  -0.001       \\
    & [-1.67]   & [0.04]    & [0.04]    & [0.04]    & [-1.08]       \\
Y   &           &           & -0.001    & -0.001    &               \\
    &           &           & [-1.06]   & [-1.00]   &               \\
    \midrule
Controls
    & {No}      & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}         \\
Group FEs
    & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {No}      & {No}      & {Yes}         \\
Family FEs
    & {No}      & {No}      & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {No}          \\
Individual FEs
    & {No}      & {No}      & {No}      & {Yes}     & {No}          \\
Family-Individual Clustering
    & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}         \\
Observations
    & 8,895     & 7,654     & 7,654     & 7,654     & 4,538         \\
R-squared
    & 0.48      & 0.53      & 0.40      & 0.41      & 0.54          \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

After that result in case that the rectangles around now colored rows are required for some reason, i would investigate how to properly use `tikzmark` for drawing them.

I guess that frames around rows should be as show next image. for it some changes to above *mwe* are done. indicated are with `% <---`:

[image]

To obtain above image of table the *mwe* had to be compiled at least twice.

```
\documentclass[table,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm, text margin right=7mm}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{\textbf{#1}}}
\setlength\aboverulesep{1pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{1pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tikz}                % <-------
\usetikzlibrary{calc, tikzmark}  % <-------

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Subsample test}
\label{tab:SR-2b}
    \scriptsize%footnotesize
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
            >{\bfseries}l
            *{6}{S[detect-mode,
                   %input-symbols =  ()[] ,
                   table-space-text-pre ={(},
                   table-space-text-post={)},
                  table-align-text-pre =false,
                  table-align-text-post=false,
                   table-format=-1.3]}
                    }
        \toprule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: Group A}}                       \\
        \midrule
    & \mcx{(1)} & \mcx{(2)} & \mcx{(3)} & \mcx{(4)} & \mcx{(5)}     \\
        \midrule
\tikzmark{a1}    % <-------
A $\cdot$ B
    &  0.006    &  0.006    &  0.006    &  0.006    &  0.005        \\
    & [4.05]    & [2.58]    & [3.29]    & [3.06]    & [4.06]\tikzmark{a2}   \\    % <-------
    \addlinespace[2pt]
A   &  -0.004   &  -0.003   &  -0.003   &  -0.003   &  -0.003       \\
    & [-6.81]   & [-3.49]   & [-4.10]   & [-3.05]   & [-3.35]       \\
    \addlinespace[2pt]
B   &           &           &  -0.002   &  -0.002   &               \\
    &           &           & [-1.60]   & [-1.55]   &               \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\textbf{Panel B: Group X}}                       \\
    \midrule
\tikzmark{b1}   % <-------
 X $\cdot$ Y
    &  0.003    &  0.002    &  0.002    &  0.002    &  0.002        \\
    & [1.44]    & [1.28]    & [1.40]    & [1.32]    & [1.24]\tikzmark{b2}   \\    % <-------
    \addlinespace[2pt]
X   &  -0.001   &  0.000    &  0.000    &  0.000    &  -0.001       \\
    & [-1.67]   & [0.04]    & [0.04]    & [0.04]    & [-1.08]       \\
Y   &           &           & -0.001    & -0.001    &               \\
    &           &           & [-1.06]   & [-1.00]   &               \\
    \midrule
Controls
    & {No}      & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}         \\
Group FEs
    & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {No}      & {No}      & {Yes}         \\
Family FEs
    & {No}      & {No}      & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {No}          \\
Individual FEs
    & {No}      & {No}      & {No}      & {Yes}     & {No}          \\
Family-Individual Clustering
    & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}     & {Yes}         \\
Observations
    & 8,895     & 7,654     & 7,654     & 7,654     & 4,538         \\
R-squared
    & 0.48      & 0.53      & 0.40      & 0.41      & 0.54          \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\tikzset{frameline/.style = {draw=#1, thick, inner sep=2pt}} % <-------
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]                % <-------
\draw[frameline=blue] ($({pic cs:a1})+(-2ex,0.8em)$)         % <-------
    rectangle ($({pic cs:a2})+(3ex,-1ex)$);                  % <-------
\draw[frameline=red] ($({pic cs:b1})+(-2ex,0.8em)$)          % <-------
    rectangle ($({pic cs:b2})+(3ex,-1ex)$);                  % <------- 
\end{tikzpicture}                                            % <-------

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this helpful explanation and guiding me through the steps. Your answer was very helpful in understanding how to reduce my question and how to use Beamer more effectively! Thanks for your help. To be honest, you just made my day!